# Stream video file and camera from Android and display it in wpf app

Tags: android, wpf, video, camera

I want to stream video file (any supported format) **from** Android phone device and display it directly in another desktop app built using WPF.

I want also to make the same thing but video comes from Camera live.

For the camera, I found some solutions. one of them is this library https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye but I have a problem with it because there is no direct url to stream. it has ip like this `http://192.168.238.102:8080/` and it opens web page with settings and buttons and the video display url is `http://192.168.238.102:8080/stream/live.jpg?id=58` which mean I should read images one by one. I don't know if this is a good streaming mechanism.

Also I found this article : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/ but it requires server implementation on the .NET side and we need to buy a license.

I still did not find something for the video playing. And also I'm looking for a simpler way for the job.

Comment: you may perhaps use droidcamx to stream to pc and capture like capturing from a webcam device.

Comment: It's not open source. How can I use it in my app ? It's even not free to try.

Comment: which side you want to develop? wpf? android? or both? if both then it may not help you as being a proprietary application. if can help if you want to develop wpf side only.

Comment: Both. I'm developing both sides